# ASP.NET Core MVC Hangfire custom authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

I managed to work Hangfire on my ASP.NET Core MVC application, and now I am trying to add admin authorization.

I added the following code to the Startup.cs file:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
 {
    Authorization = new[] {new  SecurityHelpers.AdminAuthorization.HangFireAuthorizationFilter() }
 });

app.UseHangfireServer();
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate( () => Debug.WriteLine("Minutely Job"), Cron.Minutely);
```

Now I have a problem with custom authorization filter:

```
public class HangFireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

There are samples for old configuration with IAutohorizationFilter, and form version 1.6.8 there is a new interface IDashboardAuthorizationFilter, and I can't figure out how to implement it.

My web application uses claims.

thnx

Comment: Which version of hangfire do you use?

Answer (score 29):

**To add custom basic authentication in hangfire for asp.net core**

Use Hangfire.Dashboard.Basic.Authentication nuget package.

Install using the command

```
Install-Package Hangfire.Dashboard.Basic.Authentication
```

[Reference](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.Dashboard.Basic.Authentication/)

In startup configure method add the following

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
        {
            //AppPath = "" //The path for the Back To Site link. Set to null in order to hide the Back To  Site link.
            DashboardTitle = "My Website",
            Authorization = new[]
        {
                new HangfireCustomBasicAuthenticationFilter{
                    User = _configuration.GetSection("HangfireSettings:UserName").Value,
                    Pass = _configuration.GetSection("HangfireSettings:Password").Value
                }
            }
        });
```

Add the following in the appsettings.json   (Use your username and password)

```
 "HangfireSettings": {
     "UserName": "admin",
     "Password": "password"
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the easiest one.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works with .net core 3.1, sqlite storage and memory storage

Comment: "IDX12741: JWT: 'System.String' must have three segments (JWS) or five segments (JWE)." @ArsmanAhmad

Comment: Yes @RasoolAghajani. Thanx

Comment: put this code I receive this Error in my Browser :
 "IDX12741: JWT: 'System.String' must have three segments (JWS) or five segments (JWE)."
did u know what is this ? @ArsmanAhmad

Comment: No. Actually I didn't faced it while integrating HangFire in .NET 05. @RasoolAghajani

Answer (score 18):

Here's my implementation for .NET Core:

```
public class HangfireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter {
    private string policyName;

    public HangfireAuthorizationFilter(string policyName) {
        this.policyName = policyName;
    }

    public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context) {
        var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
        var authService = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();
        return authService.AuthorizeAsync(httpContext.User, this.policyName).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Succeeded;
    }
}
```

Set it up in the `Startup` `Configure` with:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard(
            pathMatch: "/hangfire",
            options: new DashboardOptions() {
                Authorization = new IDashboardAuthorizationFilter[] {
                    new HangfireAuthorizationFilter("somePolicy")
                }
            });
```

Make sure that the policy you've chosen (eg. "somePolicy") is set up previously in `Startup` `ConfigureServices`. For example:

```
services.Configure<AuthorizationOptions>(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("somePolicy", policy => {
        // require the user to be authenticated
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        // Maybe require a claim here, if you need that.
        //policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "some role claim");
    });
});
```

Comment: @FarajFarook Any chance you could elaborate? I have this working on .NET Core 1.0.1, there's a chance something has changed on 1.1.

Comment: Shit man. My bad. I forgot the `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` I will check the whole solution and give you a thumbs up if it works. I'm sorry for the confusion from my end.

Comment: For some reason my Dashboard Context is not authenticated. I use the UserManager to sign in through the AccountController.

Comment: I should probably have been clearer about this in my answer, but have you made sure that the policy you feed into `HangfireAuthorizationFilter` (in this example "somePolicy") is a valid policy that you've set up? I'll update my answer.

Comment: Worked quite well with https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop Role Authorization sample

Answer (score 5):

If you are using .NET Core 2.0, you would need a custom implementation to comply with the new auth standards.

You need to add a middleware.
This one's provided by HangFire in their Github page/issues.

```
public class HangfireDashboardMiddleware
{
    private readonly DashboardOptions _dashboardOptions;
    private readonly JobStorage _jobStorage;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _nextRequestDelegate;
    private readonly RouteCollection _routeCollection;

    public HangfireDashboardMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate nextRequestDelegate,
        JobStorage storage,
        DashboardOptions options,
        RouteCollection routes)
    {
        _nextRequestDelegate = nextRequestDelegate;
        _jobStorage = storage;
        _dashboardOptions = options;
        _routeCollection = routes;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var aspNetCoreDashboardContext =
            new AspNetCoreDashboardContext(_jobStorage, _dashboardOptions, httpContext);

        var findResult = _routeCollection.FindDispatcher(httpContext.Request.Path.Value);
        if (findResult == null)
        {
            await _nextRequestDelegate.Invoke(httpContext);
            return;
        }

        // attempt to authenticate against default auth scheme (this will attempt to authenticate using data in request, but doesn't send challenge)
        var result = await httpContext.AuthenticateAsync();

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // request was not authenticated, send challenge and do not continue processing this request
            await httpContext.ChallengeAsync();
        }

        if (_dashboardOptions
            .Authorization
            .Any(filter =>
                     filter.Authorize(aspNetCoreDashboardContext) == false))
        {
            var isAuthenticated = httpContext.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated;
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = isAuthenticated == true
                                                  ? (int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
                                                  : (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return;
        }

        aspNetCoreDashboardContext.UriMatch = findResult.Item2;
        await findResult.Item1.Dispatch(aspNetCoreDashboardContext);
    }
}
```

Then in your Startup.cs
You need to add this method

```
private static IApplicationBuilder UseHangfireDashboardCustom(IApplicationBuilder app,string pathMatch = "/hangfire",DashboardOptions options = null,JobStorage storage = null)
{
    var services = app.ApplicationServices;
    storage = storage ?? services.GetRequiredService<JobStorage>();
    options = options ?? services.GetService<DashboardOptions>() ?? new DashboardOptions();
    var routes = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<RouteCollection>();

    app.Map(new PathString(pathMatch), x =>
        x.UseMiddleware<HangfireDashboardMiddleware>(storage, options, routes));

    return app;
}
```

Finally, use the Custom Authorization

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute(
                       "default",
                       "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"));

        app.UseHangfireServer();

        //Voila!
        UseHangfireDashboardCustom(app);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implement `IDashboardAuthorizationFilter`

```
public class HangfireAuthorizeFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        var owinEnvironment = context.GetOwinEnvironment();
        if (owinEnvironment.ContainsKey("server.User"))
        {
            if (owinEnvironment["server.User"] is ClaimsPrincipal)
            {
                return (owinEnvironment["server.User"] as ClaimsPrincipal).Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
            else if (owinEnvironment["server.User"] is GenericPrincipal)
            {
                return (owinEnvironment["server.User"] as GenericPrincipal).Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your startup

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new [] { new HangfireAuthorizeFilter() }
});
```

Comment: Kim Hoang, when I try this one it says

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Hangfire.Core.dll

Additional information: Context argument should be of type `OwinDashboardContext`!

Comment: @Wasyster, it's weird, actually that attribute I implement it for MVC 5. But it should work the same with MVC core