# Hangfire Dashboard logout

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

As refer to this
[ASP.NET Core MVC Hangfire custom authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623551/asp-net-core-mvc-hangfire-custom-authentication)

i had use custom basic authentication for my HangFire dashboard to login. How i can logout from it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hangfire delegates all the login/logout logic to your app meaning that if you logged out from your app you logged out in Hangfire dashboard as well.