# Hang fire basic authentication not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, hangfire

I have created a new application using ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API.

Implemented HangFire with basic authentication, everything works as expected locally, but after the deployment, Hangfire always returns an `UnAuthorized` error.

Here is my `Program.cs` file:

```
service.AddControllers();
service.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
service.AddSwaggerExtension();

service.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseMemoryStorage());

service.AddHangfireServer();

service.AddHostedService<HangFireHostedService>();
service.AddSingleton<IChannelManager, ChannelManager>();
service.AddSingleton<IDataSourceManager, DataSourceManager>();
service.AddSingleton<IDataService, DataService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions()
{
    DashboardTitle = "Hangfire Dashboard",
    IgnoreAntiforgeryToken = true,
    Authorization = new[]{
    new HangfireCustomBasicAuthenticationFilter{
      User = app.Configuration["Hangfire:Username"],
                Pass = app.Configuration["Hangfire:Password"]
    }
}
});

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHangfireDashboard();
app.Run();
```

Comment: Please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623551/asp-net-core-mvc-hangfire-custom-authentication . I think your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

use this example:

Step 1:

Install this package:

```
Hangfire.Dashboard.BasicAuthorization
```

Step 2:

Add this code in startup:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilter(
                    new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilterOptions
                    {
                        RequireSsl = false,
                        SslRedirect = false,
                        LoginCaseSensitive = true,
                        Users = new[]
                        {
                            new BasicAuthAuthorizationUser
                            {
                                Login = "Admin",
                                PasswordClear = "123"

                            }
                        }
                    }) }
});
```